# Make `git rebase -i` present and apply commits bottom to top

Tags: git, rebase, git-interactive-rebase

Git shows commits in the interactive-rebase todo list (produced by `git rebase -i`) in the opposite of the usual order: the most ancestral commit (typically, the oldest commit) is shown first, not last.

Can I get it the other way around, for consistency with the usual sort order of `git log`? That is, I'd like the todo list shown in the default sort order of `git log`, and I'd like the todo list to still be understood by Git after I've edited it, without having to manually re-reverse it.

Comment: its a timeline - if you want to do things in the opposite order, do one commit at a time

Comment: Certainly the reasons are clear. This is not a list of commits. it is, as you rightly term it, a todo list. It lists _actions_, things to do, in order; each line starts with an imperative verb (or its abbreviation). I don't know any world in which the first thing to do comes at the bottom of the list, and the last thing to do comes at the top.

Comment: @DanielA.White I could be wrong, but it seems very likely there's a slicker way to do it than that.

Comment: Why not manually reverse it? Unless git-rebase(1) has that option you’re out of luck.

Comment: @Guildenstern I think doing this manually would be error-prone.

Comment: Sure. What I meant is that you want git(1) to understand your reversed list. It seems that it won’t. So you could manually fix that in the sense of: make a script that acts as an intermediary between you and git(1). It doesn’t have to be manual in the sense of with-your-hands.

Comment: @Guildenstern I see. Yeah, that might be the best option.

Comment: `:%!tac` is error prone? "Here's a nickel, kid. Get yourself a better editor."

Comment: It's probably `git log` that's upside down, rather than `git rebase -i`...

Comment: @TTT it isn't really because you can choose (`git log --reverse`)

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429494/14998487). See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/14998487) for how this may affect this question.

Comment: @sehe It's possible to view the log in both directions so one of them could be thought of as "right side up" and the other as "upside down". My (half joking) comment was pointing out that the default "show me the history" starts at the top and goes backwards in time, so perhaps that's the direction that is backwards. And it's a good thing it's backwards because 99.999% of the time that's what we all want to see when using `git log`.  Rebase on the other hand, is a ordered TODO list so it makes sense to go oldest first. (Unless you're so used to looking at git log you want to see it reversed.)

Comment: @TTT I agree 100%. It's also true (as the answer(s) prove) that you could equip rebase with a corresponding `--reverse` option. For no reason :)

Comment: `git log` prints the newest commits first, because each commit records its parent(s) hashes. If `log` were to print in reverse order by default, you would need to read the full history until the very first commit to then print it in reverse. By printing each commit as encountered, you can stream the output (and can stop reading commits when you are no longer viewing the log)

Comment: @knittl great point. So maybe one could say `git log` prints in reverse order because it's what we want to see **and** it's far more efficient that way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a custom `sequence.editor` config:

```
git -c sequence.editor='tac "$1" > "$1.reverse" && "$(git config core.editor || echo "${GIT_EDITOR:-${EDITOR:-vi}}")" "$1.reverse" && tac "$1.reverse" > "$1"' rebase -i ...
```

It's easy to configure a reusable alias for that and use it:

```
git config alias.revbase "!git -c sequence.editor='tac \"\$1\" > \"\$1.reverse\" \
&& \"\$(git config core.editor || echo \"\${GIT_EDITOR:-${EDITOR:-vi}}\")\" \"\$1.reverse\" \
&& tac \"\$1.reverse\" > \"\$1\"' rebase -i"
git revbase @~10
```

Here's an approach that keeps the commented-out interactive-rebase hints on the bottom, and changes the line "top to bottom" to "bottom to top".

```
function gri {
    local cmd='
        grep -v "^#\|^\$" "$1" | tac >"$1.reverse" &&
        grep "^#\|^\$" "$1" | sed "s/top to bottom/bottom to top/" >"$1.hints" &&
        cat "$1.reverse" "$1.hints" >"$1.gri" &&
        $EDITOR "$1.gri" &&
        tac "$1.gri" >"$1"'
    git -c sequence.editor="$cmd" rebase -i "$@"
}
```